# How can I stop make from segfaulting?

Tags: android, build, compilation, makefile

I've been trying to build cyanogenmod, although for the purposes of this questions I suspect it might be just any large project. I've tried three different versions of Ubuntu with three different versions of make, and no matter what version I switch to, make crashes at some point during compilation:

```
make: *** [out/target/product/passion/symbols/system/lib/liblog.so] Segmentation fault
```

Is this a behavior of make, or could this be android-specific?

Comment: Segfaults are usually the result of a program trying to access memory that it doesn't own. The error probably a bug in the code you are trying to compile.

Comment: This code isn't being run, it's being compiled. It's not accessing *any* memory.

Comment: Segfault occur during runtime, not compile time. So it could be an error in your compiler. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault

Comment: I know that much, but I was hoping someone could tell me how to make the make/gcc/g++ toolchain avoid this problem.

Comment: If you haven't made any changes to the CM sources I'd ask them they'd probably appreciate the bug report. If you have made changes try building the pure CM sources and see if you get the same problem.

Comment: This is a completely vanilla build, but that's bothering me is that this is happening in multiple places on multiple systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution: I was building on a Linux VM in a shared directed that lived on Mac OS. Upon checking out my code in the VM's hard drive, everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

make is not segfaulting. The problem is likely with the cross-compilation toolchain you are using.

The message you quote is telling you that make ran some program in order to create "out/target/product/passion/symbols/system/lib/liblog.so", and *that program*, whatever it is, segfaulted.

To find out what's really going wrong, you need to look at the preceding output from the build process. Unless you're running make the "-j" option, it's likely that the line immediately above this message identifies the program that segfaulted.